# Context returning undefined

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks

I have a context that contains an array, this context has a function that updates a certain value in that array:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const SliderValueContext = createContext()

export function SliderValueProvider({ children }) {

    const [intensity, setIntensity] = useState([
        {
            EXAMPLE0: 0,
        },
        {
            EXAMPLE1: 0,
        },
        {
            EXAMPLE2: 0,
        },
    ])

    const updateCertainIntensity = (value, index) => {

        console.log('Index: ' + index)
        console.log('Value: ' + value)
        let newIntensity = [...intensity]
        newIntensity[index] = value

        setIntensity(newIntensity)
    }

    return (

        <SliderValueContext.Provider
        
            value={{intensity, updateCertainIntensity}}>

            {children}

        </SliderValueContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I have a basic StackNavigator with both of my screens:

```
import React from 'react'

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import Index from './index'

import SliderScreen from './screen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function MyStack() {

    return (

        <Stack.Navigator>

            <Stack.Screen name='Index' component={Index}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='SliderScreen' component={SliderScreen}/>

        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

This is how my index looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

import {

    Button

} from 'react-native'

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

import { SliderValueProvider } from './context'

export default function Index() {

    const navigation = useNavigation()

    return (

        <SliderValueProvider>

            <Button title='YOU' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SliderScreen')}></Button>

        </SliderValueProvider>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {

  return (

            <NavigationContainer>

              <MyStack>


              </MyStack>

            </NavigationContainer>

  )
}
```

Custom Slider component:

```
export default function SliderGroup({ id, text, borderColor }) {

    const { updateCertainIntensity } = useContext(SliderValueContext)

    return (

        <View style={[styles.slider_container, { borderColor: borderColor }]}>

            <View style={styles.slider_container_text}>

                <Text style={styles.text_style}> {text} </Text>

                {/* <Text style={styles.number_style}>  </Text> */}

            </View>

            <View style={styles.slider_container_slider}>

                <Slider

                    onValueChange={(value) => updateCertainIntensity(value, id)}
                    step={1}
                    minimumValue={0}
                    maximumValue={5}
                    maximumTrackTintColor='rgb(255, 255, 255)'
                />

            </View>

        </View>
    )
}
```

Problem: Whenever I try to access the useContext in my custom Slider component, it says that the context is undefined `undefined is not an object (evaluating useContext.updateCertainIntensity)` .Other contexts however, work just fine, but they are not using objects, just simple strings. Does it have to do with using an object in useState()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't wrapping your app inside the context you just created.

In your App.jsx

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <SliderValueProvider> {/* this one is going to feed its children with data */}
        <MyStack /> {/* this will be fed by the parent component */}
    </SliderValueProvider>
</NavigationContainer>
```